# Restricting a date between two specific dates, SQL Developer Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, ddl, create-table

How to check if inputted date is between 2 set dates (preferably a set date and the current date)

I'm creating the BOK table, and want the AAR (Year) to be between 1900 and current year (can be specified manually), Note I'm not very experienced with this and still learning.  Using Oracle SQL developer.

```
   CREATE TABLE BOK
    (
    ISBN      VARCHAR2(50),
    TITTEL    VARCHAR2(50),
    UTGIVER   VARCHAR2(50),
    AAR       DATE     CHECK (AAR between'1900/01/01' AND '2017/01/01')
    )
Error starting at line : 1 in command -

Error report -
ORA-01861: stringconstant doesnt match formatstring
01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
*Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
           the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
           "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
           with no extra whitespace.
*Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a string to specify a date value. This causes the database to attempt to convert it to a date with its default format, which fails since your string doesn't match that format. Instead of relying on this default format, you would be better served specifying it explicitly:

```
CREATE TABLE BOK
(
    ISBN      VARCHAR2(50),
    TITTEL    VARCHAR2(50),
    UTGIVER   VARCHAR2(50),
    AAR       DATE CHECK (AAR between TO_DATE('1900/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND 
                                      TO_DATE('2017/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this would work in the short term, however.  Isn't there a way to implement the current date?  between 1900 and current year.  I want the datebase to be low maintenance in the layout level.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `date` prefix:

```
AAR       DATE     CHECK (AAR between date '1900-01-01' AND date '2017-01-01')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I ended up going for mureiniks' answer since i saw it first.  But yours would probably be just as good!

Comment: @Peebl . . . That's fine.  Mureinik has very good answers.  You can mouse over the time to see exactly when answers were submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Like Gordon, I like the ANSI standard date literal (for dates that don't have a time-of-day component).

Note, however, that "between" is inclusive of both endpoints. If you want the year to be between 1900 and the current year, the condition should be

```
check (aar >= date '1900-01-01' and aar < date '2017-01-01')
```

Note that `<= date '2016-12-31'` would work only if it was guaranteed that `aar` never has a time-of-day component (such as `09:30:00`) but it is generally a poor practice to rely on such things.

Although... you explained "aar" means "year." But it is in DATE data type. So what is it - a "date" that is required to always be January 1 at 00:00:00? Strange.

Then, you mentioned SYSDATE. Alas, SYSDATE may have different values on different calls, and therefore it (and any other similar functions or expressions containing them) is illegal in check constraints. A check condition should either be true or false regardless of who is checking it, where, or when. There are ways around that if it's a requirement (for example there could be a "date_created" column, with SYSDATE used to populate it, and the check constraint can be at the table level, across the two columns).

Comment: Could use a trigger to enforce the "must be less than today" requirement

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by " So what is it - a "date" that is required to always be January 1 at 00:00:00?"

Comment: Keep forgetting i can't press enter here for a line...
What i mean with my question is, I want ANY inputed date of a book release (aar = year in norwegian, and bok is book), but the database is only supposed to store books released after 1900, and before the current date.